How can I remove predicted text from the iOS keyboard in my kivy app?
When I am running my kivy app on ios and use a TextInput, the iOS keyboard has the predictive text bar on top of it.

I would like to remove this from the keyboard. I have tried using all of the different input_type options, but they don't make any difference. I can't find anybody else online that has had the same issue. I have seen solutions for this with swift, but need this to be implemented in my python file. I know the user can turn this off in the system settings, but I want this done within the context of my program.
Example code that produces this issue:
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return TextInput()


MyApp().run()


Thanks for any help.
